# Running total only returns the last entry for the month - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have the below table

| Sku | Date | Rolling Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 01/02/2021 | 10 |
| SKU1 | 02/02/2021 | 15 |
| SKU1 | 03/02/2021 | 7 |
| SKU2 | 01/02/2021 | 15 |
| SKU2 | 02/02/2021 | 18 |
| SKU2 | 03/02/2021 | 30 |
| SKU1 | 01/03/2021 | 7 |
| SKU1 | 02/03/2021 | 15 |
| SKU1 | 03/03/2021 | 18 |
| SKU2 | 01/03/2021 | 10 |
| SKU2 | 02/03/2021 | 30 |
| SKU2 | 03/03/2021 | 143 |

I am trying to create a sql query which will return the last record for each month along with the total. Something like this

| SKU | Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SKU1 | 03/02/2021 | 7 |
| SKU2 | 03/02/2021 | 30 |
| SKU1 | 01/03/2021 | 7 |
| SKU2 | 01/03/2021 | 10 |

I have tried lots of ways to produce this but I cannot get anything to come close.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi! Please follow this guidelines when posting a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm a bit lost . . . The results do not seem consistent with the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Without any data examples, I think you may want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY sku
           ORDER BY date DESC)
         , count = sum(qty)
         , sku
    FROM yourtable
    group by sku, date
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your solution below I am getting the following error

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 32
Column 'yourtable.Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SKU
           ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
         , count = sum(Rolling_Total)
         , SKU
    FROM yourtable
    group by SKU
) a
WHERE a.rn = 1

Comment: That just means I forgot to add date to the group by. But it looks like you tried to run what I wrote. You need to modify the "yourtable" with the name of the table you're querying.